# Unable to run python programs in powershell

Tags: python-2.7

While I have python running in powershell trying to do my work from 'learn python the hard way', I keep having an issue where the python files no longer open. for example a file named 'ex1.py' will not run and will instead return this error message:

> > > ex1.py
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "(stdin)", line 1, in (module)
> > >       NameError:name 'ex1' is not defined

in the third line of code the text in parenthesis are actually in angle brackets but typing them that way makes them not show up.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
import ex1
```

without the .py extension, then use whatever you have in there by calling `ex1.function()`.